# Flutter Document Collaboraion

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, document, collaboration

Is there any way to use the following link's structure to build app in flutter?

I want to make a document collaborated app.

https://www.pdftron.com/blog/android/build-real-time-collab-with-firebase-1/

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

- Build the project in Flutter with Firebase support by reviewing the
  official [Flutter docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/firebase).
- Build the User Interface using Flutter widgets (see sample below and customize for your usage)
- Get the [PDFTron/Flutter SDK](https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/android/flutter/)
- Build the [document viewer](https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/android/get-started/flutter/view-a-document/) in Flutter (this is a flutter code sample)
- Read the other samples and cookbooks for more info at the same [site](https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/android/flutter/)
- Additional setup for having the Firebase work on the iOS side
  will be needed. See the Firebase docs noted earlier and this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DqJ_KjFzL9I&t=38s) for an overview

Answer (score 0):

Just scrubbing a bit through PDFtron [docs](https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/android/get-started/flutter/add-an-api/) and you will realize they offer pretty neat support for flutter.
As written in the docs you can access all native APIs, so you can achieve the same result from your link with the structure custom-tailored for your needs.

There is even a flutter [repo](https://github.com/PDFTron/pdftron-flutter) with a wrapper that you can start at.